# How to take a letter input and use an if statement to determine what a variable will be equal to?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, input

Im making a test code for a super simple program a friend will use for his business. If the customer wants mint they'd enter <kbd>y</kbd> if not they'd enter <kbd>n</kbd>.

So what can I input to make this work?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kloud1{

  public static void main(String[]args){

    boolean exitloop = false;

    while (!exitloop){

      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("KK  KK LL       OOOOO  UU   UU DDDDD");
      System.out.println("KK KK  LL      OO   OO UU   UU DD  DD  ");
      System.out.println("KKKK   LL      OO   OO UU   UU DD   DD ");
      System.out.println("KK KK  LL      OO   OO UU   UU DD   DD ");
      System.out.println("KK  KK LLLLLLL  OOOO0   UUUUU  DDDDDD  ");

      System.out.print("Enter amount of people in group:");
      double p= input.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter amount of desired Hookahs");
      double h= input.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Would they like to add mint? (enter y or n) ");
      String mint = input.nextLine();
      if (mint.equals("y")){
        int minty=5;
      }
      else if (mint.equals("n")){
        int minty=0;
      }
      double minty = (String minty);
      double y = input.nextDouble();
      double t = ((p * 5) + minty + ( h * 22)) * 1.0825 ;
      System.out.println(" The total is:" + t);
      System.out.print("Press enter");

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have with your code? Does it work, doesn't it...? Where are you having trouble? Well, I'm guessing it doesn't even compile. You're defining the `minty` variable three times, `(String minty)` is not a valid expression... `exitloop` is always false...

Comment: It doesnt compile. what i want is for the program to read that the user inputs either "y" or "n" and that makes minty equal either 5 if the user enters "y" or 0 if the user enters "n"

Comment: Compilers usually have error messages that tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring "int minty" inside of an if statement, that means its only accessible inside of the if statement.
Try this:

...

```
System.out.print("Would they like to add mint? (enter y or n) ");

String mint = input.next();
double minty = 0;
if(mint.equals("y"))
    minty+=5;

double t = ((p * 5) + minty + ( h * 22)) * 1.0825 ;
```

...

No idea what you're trying to do with double y though, you're not using it..
Also for non-decimal numbers you should use int not double, and for a single letter you should use char instead of a string.

Comment: If i wanted to make lines that only accepted numbers as entry, how would i do it? Thank you so much by the way

Comment: Not sure i understand what you mean, but i'm guessing you want this:

`
int num = -1;
  while (num == -1) {
   String s = input.nextLine();
   try {
    num = Integer.parseInt(s);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
`

Comment: You seem new to java. I recommend you learn from this website, it's great:
       buckysroom.org/videos.php